# Sum of squares in geometric progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometric-progressions

> In the geometric progression $b_1, b_2, b_3,\ldots, b_1+b_3+b_5=10$
>   and $b_2+b_4=5$. Find the sum of the squares of the first five terms.

If you solve for the first term and the common ratio, you will get nasty radicals and then squaring and adding is not a good option. How do I do it then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $(b_1+b_3+b_5)^2-(b_2+b_4)^2$.

More suggestions: $(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2xz+2yz$, $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$ (this you know, I guess), now use the fact that in geometric progression one has $b_{n-1}b_{n+1}=b_{n}^{2}$.

Comment: After solving what you gave, I am left with $50=b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2+b_4^2+b_5^2-2b_5$

Comment: @Garvil I don't see any leftover terms.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. My bad.

Comment: No problem. And damn... I never get accepted answers because I'm always the second to post the answer :D Thanks for the upvote. Will edit when possible.

Comment: Garvil, can you change the accepted answer, please? Let us support enthusiastic young people :)

Comment: ^ Janko why? You clearly gave the hint, and that too first! There's no reason to change accepted answers! I even upvoted your answer immediately after uploading mine because it was concise and neat. There's no reason for your answer to not be the accepted one :)

Comment: @JankoBracic how did you think of that? One would obviously first solve for the first term and then the common ratio and then work it out. Nice +1.

Answer (score 2):

Let $b_1=a$, and the common ratio be $r$. Given that
$$a+ar^2+ar^4=10 \qquad\text{and}\qquad ar+ar^3=5.$$
What is the value of
$$(a)^2 +(ar)^2 +(ar^2)^2 +(ar^3)^2 +(ar^4)^2?$$
Realize that:
$$(a+ar^2+ar^4)^2 -(ar+ar^3)^2$$
simplifies to the required sum. On substituting:
$$(10)^2 -(5)^2 = (10+5)(10-5) = 75.$$

Comment: Note: Janko seems to have already given you the big hint. And no, it simplifies properly into those five terms. @Garvil

Comment: 20 terms cancel out; remaining five are the required five.